# Recursive type_traits for member function detection

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to apply the type_trait `has_fun` recursively so that `C` enables its `fun` member function only if `T` has one.
Is there a way to make `C::fun` being conditionally detected?

```
template <typename T>
    struct has_fun {
        template <class, class> class checker;
        template <typename U>
        static std::true_type test(checker<U, decltype(&U::fun)> *);
        template <typename U>
        static std::false_type test(...);
        static const bool value = std::is_same<std::true_type, decltype(test<T>(nullptr))>::value;
      };

struct A {
    void fun(){
        std::cout << "this is fun!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    void not_fun(){
        std::cout << "this is NOT fun!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct C {
    void fun() {
        static_assert(has_fun<T>::value, "Not fun!");
        t.fun();
    }
    T t;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::cout << has_fun<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_fun<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_fun<C<A>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_fun<C<B>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
1
```

Expected output:

```
1
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the compiler to SFINAE on the method.

All checks that happen in templates only take into account the **signatures** of the functions, so the static_assert that you used will not be considered.

The solution is to add a check in the signature.

Intuitively you would write

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    std::enable_if_t<has_fun<T>::value> fun() {
        t.fun();
    }

    T t;
};
```

But this will not produce what you expect: the compiler will refuse to compile C, even if you don't call C.fun();

Why?

The compiler is allowed to evaluate code and issue errors if it can prove it will never work.
Since when you declare C the compiler can prove that foo() will never be allowed, it will fail compilation.

To solve the issue you can force the method to have a dependent type, so that the compiler can't prove that it's always going to fail.

Here is the trick

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    template<typename Q=T, typename = if_has_fun<Q>>
    void fun() {
        t.fun();
    }

    T t;
};
```

The compiler can't prove that Q will always be T, and we check Q, not T, so the check is going to be performed only when you invoke fun.

Full working solution at https://wandbox.org/permlink/X32bwCqQDb288gVl

Note: I used the detector which is in experimental, but you can use your detector.

You need to replace the true test though, in order to check that the function can be properly called.

```
template <typename U>
static std::true_type test(checker<U, decltype(std::declval<U>().fun())> *);
```

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/MpohZzxvZdurMArP

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class,class,class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>,Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;

template<class T, class...Args>
using dot_fun_r=decltype(std::declval<T>().fun(std::declval<Args>()...));

template<class T, class...Args>
using can_dot_fun = can_apply<dot_fun_r, T, Args...>;
```

`can_dot_fun` is a slicker version of `has_fun`.

```
temple<class U=T&,
  std::enable_if_t< can_dot_fun<U>{}, bool > =true
void fun() {
    static_cast<U>(t).fun();
}
```

Now `C<B>{}.fun()` is not valid, so `can_dot_fun< C<B>> >` is false.

This answer uses [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) for brevity, but the pieces can be written as far back as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) (like `void_t`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I propose you a little simplified version of your `has_fun` type traits

```
template <typename T>
struct has_fun
 {
   template <typename U>
   static constexpr auto test (int)
      -> decltype( &U::fun, std::true_type{} );

   template <typename U>
   static constexpr std::false_type test (...);

   static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(1))::value;
 };
```

This works to detect if for the type `T` is available one (and only one) member `fun` (`&T::fun`), regardless if it's a variable or a function, regardless the signature of the function (if it's a function).

Can be useful but consider that doesn't works when (1) there are more `fun()` overloaded methods and (2) when `fun()` is a template method.

Using this you can, by example, write (SFINAE enabling/disablig `fun()`) the `C` container as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct C
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   auto fun() -> typename std::enable_if<has_fun<U>::value>::type
    {
      static_assert(has_fun<T>::value, "Not fun!");
      t.fun();
    }

    T t;
 };
```

And this works, because you can write

```
C<A> ca;

ca.fun();
```

But if you try to print the `has_fun<C<A>>` value

```
std::cout << has_fun<C<A>>::value << std::endl;
```

you see that you get zero because the `fun()` function in `C<A>` is a template one.

Not only: if the `fun()` function in `T` ins't a `void` function, the line

```
  t.fun();
```

in the `C::fun()` function, cause an error.

Suggestion: change your `has_fun` type traits to check, simulating a call with `std::declval()`, if `T` has a `fun()` method with a precise signature (`void(*)(void)`, in your case)

```
template <typename T>
struct has_fun
 {
   template <typename U>
   static constexpr auto test (int)
      -> decltype( std::declval<U>().fun(), std::true_type{} );

   template <typename U>
   static constexpr std::false_type test (...);

   static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(1))::value;
 };
```

Now also `has_fun<C<A>>::value` is true because works also in case of overloading and template function; now the `C::fun()` method is safe because is enabled only if `T` has a `fun()` method with the correct signature.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct has_fun
 {
   template <typename U>
   static constexpr auto test (int)
      -> decltype( std::declval<U>().fun(), std::true_type{} );

   template <typename U>
   static constexpr std::false_type test (...);

   static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(1))::value;
 };

struct A
 { void fun(){ std::cout << "this is fun!" << std::endl; } };

struct B
 { void not_fun(){ std::cout << "this is NOT fun!" << std::endl; } };

template <typename T>
struct C
 {
   template <typename U = T>
   auto fun() -> typename std::enable_if<has_fun<U>::value>::type
    {
      static_assert(has_fun<T>::value, "Not fun!");
      t.fun();
    }

    T t;
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << has_fun<A>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_fun<B>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_fun<C<A>>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << has_fun<C<B>>::value << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with two implementations of C, one with fun, the other without, and an extra std::enable_if_t artempte argument:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<has_fun<T>::value> * = nullptr>
struct C
{
 void fun()
 { ... }
};
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!has_fun<T>::value> * = nullptr>
struct C
{
  // no fun()
};
```

If most of C would actually be shared between the two cases you might also spin that shared part off into a base.